# The dimension of the normal cone of a face in a polytope

Tags: geometry, algebraic-geometry, polyhedra, polytopes, tropical-geometry

Let $P$ is a polytope in $\mathbb{R}^n$ if $F$ is one of its faces of dimension $d$ then the dimension of its normal cone $\mathcal{N}(F)$ is $n-d$.\

This seems to be intuitively obvious but I can't write an explicit proof of it.
Such an statement is written as one of the properties of normal fans on Wikipedia [(here)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_fan)  and as a reference it suggests the book "Lectures on Polytopes" by Ziegler, I searched a lot in his book but I couldn't find such an statement, maybe since I am really new in this field and I don't know much it is stated somehow indirectly and one can deduce this from some other statement.
I would be really grateful if someone can help me to find an explicit proof for this statement.

Comment: You can find a proof in this paper https://shulu.web.unc.edu/wp-content/uploads/sites/16849/2018/04/080124-Normal-Fan.pdf

Comment: Many thanks for your reply, actually I wrote a comment on it and as I didn't receive any answer for that I checked here again and it seems that was not sent for some reason. By the way, let me leave the comment again: I checked the paper you sent and unfortunately I couldn't find such an statement in it, can you tell me more precisely where in this paper I can find the statement?

Comment: Answered on [MO](https://mathoverflow.net/q/404469/108884).